# Flutter - how to call multiple builder items in material app?

Tags: flutter, material-design, builder

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      builder: BotToastInit(), //1. call BotToastInit
      navigatorObservers: [BotToastNavigatorObserver()],
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Pak Coins',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MySplashScreen(),
    );
  }
}
```

this is my MyApp Class where want to call 2 builder

1. BotToastInit(),
2. EasyLoading.init()
   how i call both of this?
   builder: //here ,

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `builder` parameter must return one widget. If you like to do initialization or return two widgets, you've to nest them yourself inside the `builder`:

```
builder: (context, child) {
    // do your initialization here
    child = EasyLoading.init();  // assuming this is returning a widget
    child = botToastBuilder(context,child);
    return child;
  }
```

if you look at the getting started guide of [bot_toast package](https://pub.dev/packages/bot_toast), they've an example at step 3.

**Update:** Or utilize the builder methods provided by BotToast or EasyLoading such as:

```
builder: EasyLoading.init(builder: BotToastInit()),
```

Comment: because flutter has a widget tree. MaterialApp, unlike Column or Row, only has a single child. To work around this issue, you've to nest the children one above the other. `EasyLoading.init()` doesn't seem to have a child parameter, but botToast can have a child so you pass the former as a child to the latter.

Comment: why not use a streambuilder to get the data then use a setstate to update the widget tree with the data.

Comment: Updated solution saved my day.

Answer (score 19):

Here is the solution.

The build items I want to call are: `DevicePreview.appBuilder` , `BotToastInit()` and `EasyLoading.init()` .

**So the solution will be as follows:**

```
 builder: (context, myWidget){
             myWidget = DevicePreview.appBuilder(context, myWidget);
             myWidget = BotToastInit()(context, myWidget);
             myWidget = EasyLoading.init()(context,myWidget);
             return myWidget;
           },
```

Comment: Thank you, It worked!!

Comment: EasyLoading.init()(context,myWidget); save my day.